# What is the correct way to perform long-running operation outside the EDT?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

In a desktop Java 1.5 application (it has to run on a lot of MacOS X machines that will nerver see a 1.6 VM due to Apple politics) what is a correct way to perform a lengthy computation outside the EDT?

Say, for example, when the user clicks on a button that starts an operation: I get the notification on the EDT and I want to run some method (say `crunchData()`).

Here's one way to do it:

```
        final Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                crunchData();
            }
        } );
        t.start;
```

I mean: this does what I want but every single time the user starts a potentially long running task I use the above idiom.  And I feel like I'm always unnecessarily creating lots of task (moreover although sometimes the operation can be lengthy, sometimes it won't and in these case I'd like the app as responsible as possible).

Another way to do it would be to have another (non-EDT) thread (or a pool of threads), always running, say waiting on a blocking queue and executing, say, *Runnable* that I would enqueue wherever I need to perform a lengthy operation.

What is *the* correct way to deal with this?

**EDIT:** Is the correct way to deal with something that simple to install `SwingWorker`? How did people deal with this (which seems pretty basic) before `SwingWorker` came?

Comment: What happens if the last run of crunchdata has not finished? Does your code need to: cancel the running instance; not start the new instance; or wait for the running instance to complete before starting a new instance.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller: this is already taken care of.  Some can run in parallel, some other cancel the previously running instances, etc.  It's really more about how to typically do this under Java (1.5, where I've got no SwingWorker by default).

Comment: in response to your edit, people still used `SwingWorker`, or, riffing off the code provided in the comments to the answer below by Riduidel, wrote something very similar.  Package it with your code.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way is to have your EDT code start a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), which will do the job outside and return the result to you.

Comment: I'm on Java 5 (this has to run on a lot of MacOS X computers that will never ever get Java 6...  Thanks Apple ;)

Comment: @NoozNooz42 - you can get code for the old tutorial version of SwingWorker and use it, though.  It's still floating out there and was still a standard pre Java 6.

Comment: Like @justkt mentionned, SwingWorker existed before Java 6. You can always grab the code (for example here : http://www.koders.com/java/fidAC10A778A6FF41B6C3229B820BF3C864C4BF019F.aspx?s=swingworker) and backport it to Java 5.

Comment: but becareful, swingworker tend to give us a big pool and making it as a new trouble. I'm still digging about this, tough.